# Select the latest changed row in a table

Tags: mysql

I have a Mysql table `test` with the fields `id, changedate, name`.

some names have multiple changedates.

I can select all rows with

```
SELECT id, changedate, name FROM `test` ORDER BY changedate;
```

How can I select only the newest rows of that table for each name?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need the `id` (or any other column, not included in the question) but only the `name` and the newest `changedate`, then you only need a simple `GROUP BY` query - and an index on `(name, changedate)` for efficiency:

```
SELECT name, MAX(changedate) AS changedate
FROM test 
GROUP BY name ;
```

If you need more columns, one way to solve is to put the above query in a derived table and `JOIN` to the original table:

```
-- Query 1
SELECT t.*
FROM test AS t
  JOIN
  ( SELECT name, MAX(changedate) AS changedate
    FROM test 
    GROUP BY name
  ) AS g
    ON  g.name = t.name
    AND g.changedate = t.changedate ;
```

You could also use a `LEFT JOIN` or a `NOT EXISTS` solution:

```
-- Query 2a
SELECT t1.*
FROM test AS t1
  LEFT JOIN test AS t2 
    ON  t1.name = t2.name
    AND t1.g.changedate < t2.changedate
WHERE t2.name IS NULL ;

-- Query 2b
SELECT t1.*
FROM test AS t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS
      ( SELECT *
        FROM test AS t2 
        WHERE t1.name = t2.name
          AND t1.changedate < t2.changedate
      ) ;
```

Comment: really nice tips. My +1.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT id, changedate, name FROM test 
  ORDER BY changedate DESC)
as output_name GROUP BY name;
```

Comment: cool that works. so TEST should be AS output_descriptor

Comment: Don't do this. MySQL documentation clearly states: *"MySQL extends the use of GROUP BY so that the select list can refer to nonaggregated columns not named in the GROUP BY clause. This means that the preceding query is legal in MySQL. You can use this feature to get better performance by avoiding unnecessary column sorting and grouping. However, this is useful primarily when all values in each nonaggregated column not named in the GROUP BY are the same for each group. The server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, **the values chosen are indeterminate**."*

Comment: Link: **[MySQL Extensions to GROUP BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-extensions.html)**

Comment: @ypercube: so can you post a better alternative answer?

Comment: I would say in this solution, the chosen value is determinate: because the temorary table is sorted by changedate DESC, there will be chosen the first row of that result. But for other cases without a sorting you are right

Comment: @rubo77 No, I'm right anyway. The internal `ORDER BY` can be removed by an optimizer as redundant and then the query will not work as you expect (try it in the latest, 5.6 version.)

Comment: So in which mysql versions is this introduced? In 5.1 it seems to work perfect with the ORDER BY